# Как получить всё, что после определенной подстроки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка: `BIX_resourse lynx-click lynxid-unior`.

Есть шаблон работающий в PHP: `(?<=\lynxid-)(\w+)`.

В результате по совпадению он выберет: `unior`.

Помогите составить регулярку для JS. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `your_text.match(/(?:lynxid-)(\w+)/)`?

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!

Comment: @BOPOH, а ответ? :-D

Comment: @Grundy, где? не вижу )

Comment: @BOPOH, вот-вот :-) и я про то же - напиши ;-)

Comment: @Grundy, так я уже написал, что еще дописать - не знаю. В идеале надо было бы сказать, что позитивный поиск назад в js отсутствует, поэтому регулярка из php не работает и т.д., но я этого не знаю, поэтому утверждать не могу. А просто "малюсенькая строчка кода" на ответ никак не тянет, в комменте ей самое место. А расписывать что происходит в регулярке - времени нет, если автору надо - сам найдет что такое `(?:...)` и прочее

Comment: @ВОРОН, оформите мысль как ответ (а не как комментарий), чтобы вопрос мог быть помечен как "отвеченный". Только ради этого)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ВОРОН](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh) прав, в регулярках JavaScript *блоки просмотра назад* `(?<!...)`/`(?<=...)` не поддерживаются. Как бы то ни было, в подавляющем большинстве случаев *позитивный* блок просмотра назад можно заменить на обычный шаблон (т.е. можно удалить `(?<=` и `)`), а ту часть шаблона, которая находит нужный отрезок текста, необходимо заключить в захватывающие круглые скобки `(...)`. Потом, после того, как совпадение будет найдено, останется только использовать индекс необходимой группы при доступе к полученному массиву значений.

```js
var s = "BIX_resourse lynx-click lynxid-unior";
var results = s.match(/lynxid-(\w+)/) || ["", ""];
console.log(results[1]);
```

Регулярное выражение `/lynxid-(\w+)/` найдет `lynxid-`, но не выделит для этой подстроки собственный буфер, т.е. этот текст добавится к нулевому элементу конечного массива, зато `(\w+)` захватит 1 и более букв/цифр/`_` сразу после `lynxid-` и поместит это значение в отдельный буфер (в нашем случае, `results[1]`).